# How to create vector circulant matrix in Sage?

Tags: python, matrix, sage

Given the first row vector `R0 = [a0,a1,...,a(n-1)]` and a specific vector  `V`, I would like to create a "vector circulant matrix" in SAGE, which will be constructed as follows.

The rows of the matrix will be

```
R0=R0; R1=p(R0); R2=p(R1), ..., R(n-1)=p(R(n-2))
```

where `p` is a map which takes, for example row `Ri = [r0,r1,...,r(n-1)]` and 
makes it `[0, r0, r1,...,r(n-2)]+r(n-1)*V`

Note that I tried to write everything in the language of Sage. And this is not like the classical circulant, Toeplitz or Hankel matrix constructions.

(n, R0, and the vector V will be defined by the user at the beginning)

How to write a simple program that will give me the matrix  defined  above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function:

```
def f(r,v):
    def p(x):
        return vector([0]+list(x[:-1r])) + x[-1r]*v
    m = [r]
    for _ in xrange(len(r)-1r):
        m.append(p(m[-1r]))
    return matrix(m)
```

Example:

```
sage: r = vector(ZZ,(0, 1, 2, 3,))
sage: v = vector(ZZ,(3, 5, 7, 9,))
sage: f(r,v)
[   0    1    2    3]
[   9   15   22   29]
[  87  154  218  283]
[ 849 1502 2135 2765]
```

Comment: Really appreciated to get an answer this quickly, thank you very much. This seems to work with vectors and on ZZ.

Comment: I take this vectors as a list of coefficients of polynomials over Finite Fields, can you modify this function for this also? Because here we take vectors as 'lists'?

Comment: Ah. I see I just wrote r = vector(L) for list L and it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can add two lines in the function f, just before defining p, saying `r = vector(r)` and `v = vector(v)`, so that the function can accept vectors or lists.